# grunt-contrib-jshint is not ignoring specified directories

Tags: gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I have the following folders and files:

```
js/
   lib/
      jQuery.js
   compiled/
      all.js
   file1.js
   file2.js
```

I want JSHint to lint only `file1` and `file2` (without having to specify the exact files) and for it not to lint the lib folder and compiled folder.

Can anyone shed any light on why my JSHint task below is linting all .js files and not ignoring the `compiled` and `lib` folders?

```
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        all: [
            'js/**/*.js',
            '!js/compiled/**/*.js',
            '!js/lib/**/*.js'
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jshint: {
    options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
    },
    all: [
        'js/*.js',
        '!js/compiled/*.js',
        '!js/lib/*.js'
    ]
},
```

You don't need the `**` as you don't have any intermediate folders.

Comment: This is missing the wildcard in the first two declarations, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I've got problems with stack overflow editor, it does not accept my json as code and stripped the stars although :(

Comment: I fixed my message, now you should see my answer correctly.